# Handler Buttons in android custom views

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, canvas, android-canvas, android-custom-view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwTjO.png)
above is the image that i want to make in my project
it actullay is a custom view that have a textView in between
how can we make such a handling buttons in custom views and handle their clicks?

## below is the code i have in the custom view

## on cross click i want to clear canvas and on resize when i move the view then the user should be able to size increase and decrease with holding that

```
`class AutoGenerateSignature(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : FrameLayout(context, attrs) {
    private val textView: TextView
    private val undoSignActions = mutableListOf<SignActions>()
    private val redoSignActions = mutableListOf<SignActions>()

    private var textColor: Int = Color.BLACK
    private var backgroundColor: Int = Color.TRANSPARENT
    private var textSize: Float = 35f
    private var fontFamily: Typeface? = null
    private var isItalic: Boolean = false
    private var isBold: Boolean = false

    init {
        // Initialize TextView
        textView = TextView(context)
        textView.text = "Enter Name.."
        textView.setTextColor(textColor)
        textView.textSize = textSize
        val font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(
            context, R.font.primerasignature
        ) // Replace "myfont" with the actual font resource name

        textView.typeface = font

        // Add the TextView to the custom view
        val layoutParams = LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
```

type here

```
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        textView.layoutParams = layoutParams

        // Add the TextView to the custom view
        addView(textView)

    }
    fun underlineText(shouldUnderline: Boolean) {
        if (shouldUnderline) {
            textView.paintFlags = textView.paintFlags or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG
        } else {
            textView.paintFlags = textView.paintFlags and Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
        invalidate() // Redraw the view
    }
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

    }
    fun undo() {
        if (undoSignActions.isNotEmpty()) {

            val action = undoSignActions.removeAt(undoSignActions.size - 1)
            Log.d("undoActions", "undo: $action")
            redoSignActions.add(action)
            applyReverseSignAction(action) // Apply the reverse of the action
        }else{
            post {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Nothing to Redo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    fun redo() {
        if (redoSignActions.isNotEmpty()) {

            val action = redoSignActions.removeAt(redoSignActions.size - 1)
            Log.d("redoActions", "undo: $action")
            undoSignActions.add(action)
            applySignAction(action)
        }else{
            post {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Nothing to Redo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun applyReverseSignAction(action: SignActions) {
        when (action) {
            is SignActions.TextAction -> setText(action.text)
            is SignActions.ColorAction -> setTextandBg(action.textColor, action.backgroundColor)
            is SignActions.FontAction -> action.fontFamily?.let { setFOnt(it, action.isItalic, action.isBold) }
            is SignActions.SizeAction -> setTextSize(action.textSize)
            is SignActions.UnderlineAction -> underlineText(action.shouldUnderline)
        }
    }
    private fun applySignAction(action: SignActions) {
        when (action) {
            is SignActions.TextAction -> setText(action.text)
            is SignActions.ColorAction -> setTextandBg(action.textColor,action.backgroundColor)
            is SignActions.FontAction -> action.fontFamily?.let { setFOnt(it, action.isItalic, action.isBold) }
            is SignActions.SizeAction -> setTextSize(action.textSize)
            is SignActions.UnderlineAction -> underlineText(action.shouldUnderline)
        }
    }
    fun setTextColor(color: Int) {
        val previousColor = textColor
        undoSignActions.add(SignActions.ColorAction(previousColor, backgroundColor))

        textColor = color
        textView.setTextColor(color)
        invalidate() // Redraw the view
    }
    fun setTextandBg(color: Int,colors:Int) {
        val previousColor = textColor
        undoSignActions.add(SignActions.ColorAction(previousColor, backgroundColor))

        textColor = color
        textView.setTextColor(color)
        backgroundColor=colors
    }


    fun setItalic(isItalics: Boolean) {
        val previousIsItalic = isItalic
        undoSignActions.add(SignActions.FontAction(fontFamily, previousIsItalic, isBold))

        if (isItalics && isBold) {
            textView.setTypeface(fontFamily, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
            isItalic = true
        } else if (isItalics) {
            textView.setTypeface(fontFamily, Typeface.ITALIC)
            isItalic = true
        } else {
            if (isBold) {

                textView.setTypeface(fontFamily, Typeface.BOLD)
            } else {
                textView.setTypeface(fontFamily, Typeface.NORMAL)
            }
            isItalic = false
        }
        invalidate() // Redraw the view
    }

    fun setBold(isBolds: Boolean) {
        val previousIsBold = isBold
        undoSignActions.add(SignActions.FontAction(fontFamily, isItalic, previousIsBold))

        if (isBolds && isItalic) {
//            val fontFamily = Typeface.create("your_custom_font_name", Typeface.NORMAL)
//            textView.typeface = fontFamily
            textView.setTypeface(fontFamily, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
            isBold = true
        } else if (isBolds) {
            textView.setTypeface(fontFamily, Typeface.BOLD)
            isBold = true
        } else {
            if (isItalic) {

                textView.setTypeface(fontFamily, Typeface.ITALIC)
            } else {
                textView.setTypeface(fontFamily, Typeface.NORMAL)
            }
            isBold = false
        }
        invalidate() // Redraw the view
    }


    fun setBackgroundColors(color: Int) {
        val previousBackgroundColor = backgroundColor
        undoSignActions.add(SignActions.ColorAction(textColor, previousBackgroundColor))

        backgroundColor = color
        textView.setBackgroundColor(color)
        invalidate() // Redraw the view
    }

    fun setText(text: String) {
        val previousText = textView.text.toString()
        undoSignActions.add(SignActions.TextAction(previousText))
        textView.text = text
        val paddingInPixels = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_view_padding)
        textView.setPadding(paddingInPixels, paddingInPixels, paddingInPixels, paddingInPixels)
        invalidate() // Redraw the view
    }

    fun setTextSize(size: Float) {
        val previousTextSize = textSize
        undoSignActions.add(SignActions.SizeAction(previousTextSize))

        textSize = size
        textView.textSize = textSize
        invalidate() // Redraw the view
    }

fun setFOnt(font: Typeface,isItalics: Boolean,isBolds: Boolean){
    fontFamily = font
    textView.typeface = fontFamily
    setBold(isBolds)
    setItalic(isItalics)
    invalidate() // Redraw the view
}
    fun setFontFamilyWithTypeface(font: Typeface) {
//        val font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, font) // Replace "myfont" with the actual font resource name
        val previousFontFamily = fontFamily
        val previousIsItalic = isItalic
        val previousIsBold = isBold

        undoSignActions.add(SignActions.FontAction(previousFontFamily, previousIsItalic, previousIsBold))

        fontFamily = font
        textView.typeface = fontFamily

        invalidate() // Redraw the view
    }

    // Export the view as an image with specified or transparent background
    fun saveDrawingWithTransparentBackground(): Bitmap? {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        draw(canvas)

//        saveBitmapToFile(bitmap, filePath)
        return bitmap
    }

}
```

`